# Interpolating one time series onto another in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have one set of values measured at regular times. Say:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rng = pd.date_range('2013-01-01', periods=12, freq='H')
data = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
```

And another set of more arbitrary times, for example, (in reality these times are not a regular sequence)

```
ts_rng = pd.date_range('2013-01-01 01:11:21', periods=7, freq='87Min')
ts = pd.Series(index=ts_rng)
```

I want to know the value of data interpolated at the times in ts.
I can do this in numpy:

```
x = np.asarray(ts_rng,dtype=np.float64)
xp = np.asarray(data.index,dtype=np.float64)
fp = np.asarray(data)
ts[:] = np.interp(x,xp,fp)
```

But I feel pandas has this functionality somewhere in  `resample`, `reindex` etc. but I can't quite get it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can concatenate the two time series and sort by index. Since the values in the second series are `NaN` you can `interpolate` and the just select out the values that represent the points from the second series:

```
 pd.concat([data, ts]).sort_index().interpolate().reindex(ts.index)
```

or

```
 pd.concat([data, ts]).sort_index().interpolate()[ts.index]
```

Comment: You need to use method = 'values' for the key arguments in interpolate to get the same answer as in numpy  pd.concat([data, ts]).sort_index().interpolate(method = 'values')[ts.index]

Comment: Pay attention to indices that show up both in ts and in data

Answer (score 7):

Assume you would like to evaluate a time series ts on a different datetime_index. This index and the index of ts may overlap. I recommend to use the following groupby trick. This essentially gets rid of dubious double stamps. I then forward interpolate but feel free to apply more fancy methods

```
def interpolate(ts, datetime_index):
    x = pd.concat([ts, pd.Series(index=datetime_index)])
    return x.groupby(x.index).first().sort_index().fillna(method="ffill")[datetime_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a clean one liner:

```
ts = np.interp( ts_rng.asi8 ,data.index.asi8, data[0] )
```