# Interpolate one time series onto custom time series

Tags: python, pandas

**Goal:** Interpolate one time series onto another custom time series.

I checked stack overflow and found the following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955250/interpolating-one-time-series-onto-another-in-pandas). However, I get the following error:

```
 ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

**Question**: Do I need to use datetimeindex or the Unix timestamp will also work? Because the former will require me to convert to datetimeindex, then interpolate, and convert back to unixtimestamp. These are multiple steps, I would like to avoid.

Here's what I have:

The time series I would like to interpolate:

```
In [111]: p.head()
Out[111]:
       Timestamp  Pressure  Quality
0  1477294046400    101155        3
1  1477294046901    101152        3
2  1477294047421    101150        3
3  1477294047922    101151        3
4  1477294048425    101151        3
```

And the custom time series:

```
In [112]: a.head()
Out[112]:
            Time
0  1477294032458
1  1477294032463
2  1477294032468
3  1477294032473
4  1477294032478
```

Following the solution in the link above, I did the following:

```
pressure = pd.concat([p, a]).sort_index().interpolate().reindex(a.index)
```

but I get an error as shown above.

Comment: Try setting `Timestamp` and `Time` as the index axis respectively and perform the interpolation and see if it works.

Comment: Literally, the error message is telling you that `pd.concat([p, a]).sort_index().interpolate() has duplicates in the index`.  the question is what you really want the index to be and what you are trying to do? Suggestion by @NickilMaveli seems like what you may have meant to do?  Probably you need to step back and think about the concat/merge step and make sure that's what you intended.

Comment: All times in `a` come before times in `p`.  This wouldn't be interpolation, it would be backwards extrapolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide enough information so I created my own.  You will have to pay attention and adjust this to suit your needs.

This answer was given for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40034040/2336654).

***setup***

```
p = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        Pressure=[101155, 101152, 101150, 101151, 101151],
        Quality=[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
    ),
    pd.Index([0, 10, 20, 30, 40], name='Timestamp')
)

a = [5, 12, 18, 24, 33, 35, 37]
```

---

***general strategy***

- make sure timestamp is in index of `p`
- take a union of `p.index` (your timestamp) and the new time list `a`
- reindex with the union.  NaN's will show up for 'new' index values.
- when you interpolate, use `method='index'` [DOCUMENTATION](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html)

***code***

```
idx = p.index.union(a)
p.reindex(idx).interpolate('index')

p
```

[image]

```
idx = p.index.union(a)
p.reindex(idx).interpolate('index')
```

[image]

Comment: The second command results in the following error: TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that as in my example, a is a data frame and not a list. So, to conform to your suggestion, I did a.set_index('Timestamp', inplace=True). This gives me just an index data frame. The dtype of all variables is int64.

Comment: `p.set_index('Timestamp', inplace=True)` and `idx = p.index.union(a.Time)`

Comment: Thanks. The above code worked. One last thing. Given "a", I want to **only** include the values of a and not that of p. For example, the end result should have the pressure values at [5, 12, 18, 24, 33, 35, 37] only and not at [0, 10, 20, 30, 40], which are originally in p. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: p.reindex(idx).interpolate('index').reindex(a.Time)

Comment: The danger with union, I think, is that you can get duplicates. I have such for one file. So, when I use `p.reindex(idx).interpolate('index').reindex(a.Time)`, I get `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`. Now, I cannot `reset_index` as we use the index to interpolate. Is there a workaround? Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, I found a way. Thanks for your help! Really appreciate it!!