# Resampling and Interpolating Time Series in Pandas 0.14.1

Tags: python, pandas

**Objective** I have two time-series data frames, `df_template` and `this_df`. Both are at different sampling rates. I would like to resample `this_df` to `df_template` using interpolating.

**Problem**: I have the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593424/interpolate-one-time-series-onto-custom-time-series) that works in **pandas 0.19** but does not work in **pandas 0.14.1**. How do I get it to work?

```
df_template = pd.DataFrame()
this_df = pd.DataFrame()

t1 = np.arange(1484664735415, 1484664735710, 30)
t2 = np.arange(1484664735400, 1484664735700, 100)

df_template['Time'] = t1
this_df['Time'] = t2

this_df['S2'] = random.sample(xrange(50), this_df.shape[0])

this_df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
this_idx = this_df.index.union(df_template.Time)
df_new = this_df.reindex(this_idx).interpolate('index').reindex(df_template.Time)
df_new.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

The error occurs in `this_df.index.union()`.

`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'is_monotonic'`

I think there is no such function in pandas 0.14.1. So, how do I get the final result such as:

```
            Time     S2
0  1484664735415  22.25
1  1484664735445  26.75
2  1484664735475  31.25
3  1484664735505  33.95
4  1484664735535  27.65
5  1484664735565  21.35
6  1484664735595  15.05
7  1484664735625  14.00
8  1484664735655  14.00
9  1484664735685  14.00
```

Any ideas for this to work in pandas 0.14.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using outer join makes it work

```
this_idx = pd.concat([df_template, this_df], axis = 1, join = 'outer').index
df_new = this_df.reindex(this_idx).interpolate('index').reindex(df_template.index)
```