# Interpolating pandas dataframe onto axis of other dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I have two dataframes which overlap (not necessarily perfectly). I want to make comparisons between the two but am not sure how to interpolate the first onto the time axis of the second

A little silly example I've made

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def equation(x):
    return 0.5 * x + 1


def make_df(x, equation, columns=["x", "y"]):
    y = equation(x)
    df = np.c_[x, y]
    df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=columns)

    return df


# df1
xx = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
df1 = make_df(xx, equation)

# df2
xx = np.linspace(2.1, 10.1, 80)
df2 = make_df(xx, equation)
```

in this case `equation` is an arbitrary relationship which in reality will come from data. Also `df1` and `df2` will contain multiple `y` values (e.g. `y1`, `y2`, etc) given by different equations.

Furthermore the `x` between `df1` and `df2` can be non evenly spaced, and have elements which match exactly between the dataframes and some which don't.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to interpolate the `y` columns of `df1` onto the `x` of `df2`. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955250/interpolating-one-time-series-onto-another-in-pandas) seems to work for interpolating. The difficult is then removing the `x` values from `df1` and only keeping the `x` values from `df2`. That step I did by

```py
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
df3['x'] = df2['x']
df3['y'] = np.nan
temp = pd.concat([df1,df3]).sort_values(by=['x']).interpolate()
```

Reindexing `temp` here is giving the complications.

Conclusion: I'm not fixed to the solution proposed by the other article, goal is to interpolate `y` of `df1` onto `df2`'s `x` such that I'm left with a dataframe with an `x` column which matches `df2`'s.

**Edit**: Almost found a solution:

```
temp = temp.set_index('x').drop_duplicates().reindex(df2['x']).reset_index()
```

but on the real data am constantly getting `ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels` despite the return of `df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]` being

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [timestamp, vx]
Index: []
```

Note the problem area is calling `df.reindex(other_df["timestamp"])` right after dropping duplicates errors. Even setting tolerance low (1e-8) doesn't resolve errors.

Comment: `df2['y'] = np.interp(df2['x'], df1['x'], df1['y'])`?

Comment: well yep, that's much simpler and works. If you make the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried solving through pandas, turns out the simpler answer was

```
df2['y'] = np.interp(df2['x'], df1['x'], df1['y'])
```